# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Subscription' (Angular 9)

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular8, angular9

I'm trying to perform some operations on data that I'm pulling with `HttpClient` and then route the page after those operations are performed. Apparently I can't use `then` to do this, but I can't find how else to route the page *after* running the operations. Otherwise, if I try to run the operations and the routing in the same function, the page seems to try routing before the other operations are done.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NbAuthSocialLink } from '@nebular/auth';
import { NbAuthService } from '@nebular/auth';
import { DataService } from '../@core/utils/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.css']
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(
    private dataService : DataService,
    private router : Router
    ){}


  ngOnInit(){
    
  }

  textAnalysis(name, text){
    this.dataService.sendText(text).subscribe((data: any[])=>{
        
            console.log(data)

            localStorage.setItem('user_name', name)

            localStorage.setItem('insights', JSON.stringify(data)); 

            console.log('localStorage json stringified object item set to: insights')

            console.log("<----------test: should output 'Imagination'---------->")

            console.log(data['personality'][0]['children'][3]['name'])  
        
    }).then(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/pages']);
        })   
    
    }  
  }
}
```

and the `DataService` function:

```
 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



const httpOptions = {
};

declare var google: any;




@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})


export class DataService {

 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 
  public sendText(data){
    return this.http.post("//localhost:8000/personalityFromText", data, {withCredentials: true});
  }
```

Comment: Subscribing to an observable gives you a subscription, not a promise. Why can't that line be in the subscribe callback?

Comment: Could you show me what you mean?

Comment: The compiler is telling you what I mean, that's what "property 'then' does not exist on type 'Subscription'l is saying; it's *not* a promise.

Comment: Where are you calling the `textAnalysis()` function? Do you wish to wait for this function to finish before routing?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to implement then block, just put your navigation inside the subscription success block.

```
     textAnalysis(name, text){
        this.dataService.sendText(text).subscribe((data: any[])=>{
    
        console.log(data)

        localStorage.setItem('user_name', name)

        localStorage.setItem('insights', JSON.stringify(data)); 

        console.log('localStorage json stringified object item set to: insights')

        console.log("<----------test: should output 'Imagination'---------->")

        console.log(data['personality'][0]['children'][3]['name'])  
        this.router.navigate(['/pages']);
    
});
```

Comment: When I do that, it routes before the other operations finish. I was trying to get it to route 
*after* the other operations finish

Comment: It cannot route before finishing the operation. It only comes inside the subscribe success block after performing the specified asynchronous operation.

Comment: I was referring to the `localStorage` and `console.log` operations within the success callback. It routes before running those functions

Comment: Can you please write another console statement after the router statement and share a screenshot.

Comment: Nothing shows up, no logs just an ` XHR failed loading: POST ` error

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is an Observable, not a promise, so you will need to perform this using pipe, think like chains of steps, like this:

```
this.dataService.sendText(text).pipe(
    tap(data => localStorage.setItem('user_name', name)),
    tap(data => localStorage.setItem('insights', JSON.stringify(data))),
).subscribe(
    (data) => this.router.navigate(['/pages']),
    (error) => console.error(error)
);
```

There are several combinations possible using other operators than tap, take a time to read more about.

Comment: I'm still getting an `XHR failed loading: POST` error. I think I might have a deeper issue than it routing before the operations are called. I really appreciate all you guys's help, hopefully I can figure this out or post the deeper issue in another post. Thank you!

Comment: Hum, so the `post` operation fail? add error handling in your subscription logging the entire error to console. I will edit my answer adding it.

Comment: I'm still not getting anything in the console. I know the post is getting through because I can see it running the back-end operations in the terminal, but I can't receive the response here in the front-end for some reason